# JavaFX SplitPane Divider hover color css

Tags: css, javafx

I want to be able to assign a hover color via CSS to a SplitPane Divider in JavaFX.

I am able to achive this by using the following CSS

```
.split-pane:horizontal > .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.split-pane:horizontal > .split-pane-divider:hover {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

However: since the divider is lagging behind the cursor, it causes a flickering effect, since the hover is triggered whenever the divider catches up to the cursor position - but while dragging slowly, it's just a lot of flickering.

I want the hover color to be applied throughout any dragging of the divider.

Is there a way to achieve this via CSS? I tried `.split-pane-divider:focused` and `.split-pane-divider:selected`, but no luck :(

If not, is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution of Sai Dandem works, but the solution due to the comment of James_D makes it quite a bit simpler. Thanks to both of you!

For a general split-pane:

```
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider:hover,
.split-pane > .split-pane-divider:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to fix this issue is by including a new pseudo state to the `SplitPane` (when the divider is in dragging mode). And include that state in the css same as hover state.

The general idea is to set a custom pseudo state on mouse pressed filter and remove the state on mouse released. Setting the pseudo state on SplitPane will set on the divider as well, so you can set the style specifically for `.split-pane-divider:pressed`.

Something like in the below demo:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SplitPaneResizeIssueDemo extends Application {

    private final PseudoClass PRESSED_PSEUDOCLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pressed");

    public static final String CSS = "data:text/css," + // language=CSS
            """
                                    .split-pane:vertical > .split-pane-divider {
                                        -fx-background-color: transparent;
                                    }
                                    .split-pane:vertical > .split-pane-divider:hover,
                                    .split-pane:vertical > .split-pane-divider:pressed{
                                        -fx-background-color: lightblue;
                                    }
                    """;

    public static void main(final String... a) {
        Application.launch(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane(buildSplitPane());
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("SplitPane " + System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version"));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private SplitPane buildSplitPane() {
        final SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
        splitPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow;");
        splitPane.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        splitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        splitPane.setDividerPositions(.60);

        splitPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> splitPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(PRESSED_PSEUDOCLASS, true));
        splitPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> splitPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(PRESSED_PSEUDOCLASS, false));

        StackPane top = new StackPane();
        top.setMinSize(100, 10);
        top.setStyle("-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-style:solid;-fx-background-color:white;");
        StackPane bottom = new StackPane();
        bottom.setMinSize(100, 10);
        bottom.setStyle("-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-style:solid;-fx-background-color:white;");
        splitPane.getItems().addAll(top, bottom);
        HBox.setHgrow(splitPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return splitPane;
    }
}
```

*Note: Maybe set a more unique pseudo state name, as `pressed` is already existing for `Button` and may conflict if the `SplitPane` has `Button` in its children hierarchy.*

Comment: [All `Node`s have the `pressed` pseudoclass state.](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node) There's actually no need for the mouse filters or custom psuedoclass here, just adding `split-pane-divider:pressed` to the CSS selector will fix the problem.

Comment: @James_D thanks for pointing that. Till date I am not aware of this fact :). I was under the impression that pressed is only inbuilt for buttons :P.

Comment: For buttons there's the `armed` pseudo class, which is different from `pressed` in that a button can be armed by, e.g., key presses, not just mouse presses.

Comment: I usually check modena.css for any of the key references, and as :pressed is mostly used on buttons only (in that file), never thought that it is a general pseudo state ;)